# Is PBFT only used in private/permissioned blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

When a distributed ledger is using PBFT for consensus, does it mean the DLT is  necessarily private? I am asking this question because I never heard about a public DLT using PBFT.

(As you can see, I am a complete beginner: please, forgive me for my ignorance and detail your answer as much as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

A necessary prerequisite for PBFT is that all clients are known ahead of time. There are some derivates of PBFT that allow for runtime reconfiguration (BFT-SMART comes to mind), but reconfiguration comes at a performance cost and shouldn't happen constantly.

That being said, some public networks do use BFT consensus algorithms. [NEO](https://neo.org/consensus) uses 7 validators that run a [BFT algorithm](https://docs.neo.org/en-us/basic/consensus/whitepaper.html) to reach consensus. All other nodes on the network are merely auditors.

EOS also relies on a similar [algorithm called BFT-DPOS](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#consensus-algorithm-bft-dpos). All nodes use their stake to vote for block producers (21 total). These block producers run BFT consensus among each other to produce the blocks.